# What comic / cartoon style fonts are suitable for a mobile game?

Tags: fonts, font-recommendation, mobile, games

I am currently in the midst of making an iOS game. So far, I created an overall look, i.e. figures and backgrounds. However, I also have to display textual information to the user. This makes me wonder which font to use. For this, I created two mockups with different fonts.

The first one uses Avenir Next (which currently is one of my favorite fonts) with weights "Regular" and "Medium", while the second one uses Action Man with weights "Regular" and "Bold":

[image: Avenir Next]
[image: Action Man Font]

Personally, I like both mockups but would prefer the second one with the Action Man font, because in my opinion, it fits better to the overall look of the game. However, Avenir Next is probably better readable, since the font size is rather small. But I also think it kind of breaks the design, although this might not be bad.

Therefore, my question would be: is it ok to use a rather round font when the surrounding design is also round or might it be better to use a font that breaks this paradigm.

---

The requirements I can describe for the kind of font I'm looking for would be:

- Good readability with rather small font sizes (the screenshots use 36pt at an resolution of 1136 x 640 px, on the iPhone this would then be half the size)
- Two different weights, probably regular and bold
- Should fit to the game, which itself has kind of comic style
- Should not distract the player during gameplay or overly attract attention

  ---

  **What fonts are suitable for a cartoon / comic style mobile and tablet game / application?**

Comment: I think this comes down to a matter of opinion and a designer's own aesthetic view. There's no rule or restriction regarding this.

Comment: It depends on what audience you're trying to appeal to and what the gameplay is like. The second font seems readable enough to me

Comment: "because in my opinion, it fits better to the overall look of the game" = there's your answer. Don't overthink it. :)

Comment: @DA01 probably it's already too late ;)